# In base R plot, how can deploy multiple pchs to the same symbol?

Tags: r, plot, legend, symbols

```
plot(1, pch = 19, cex = 3, col = "red")
points(1, pch = 1, cex = 3, col = "black", lwd = 2)

legend("top",
   "sym",
   pch = 19,
   col = "red",
   cex = 2,
   pt.cex = 4)

legend("top",
   "sym",
   pch = 1,
   col = "black",
   cex = 2,
   pt.cex = 4)
```

In R, a black borderline can be added to a solid red circle like:

Then, how can I use the symbol with added types for the legend?

As the code shows, legends cannot be added but overlapped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `bty = "n"`

```r
plot(1, pch = 19, cex = 3, col = "red")
points(1, pch = 1, cex = 3, col = "black", lwd = 2)

legend("top",
       "sym",
       bty = "n",
       pch = 19,
       col = c("red"),
       cex = 2,
       pt.cex = 4)

legend("top",
       "sym",
       bty = "n",
       pch = 1,
       col = c("black"),
       cex = 2,
       pt.cex = 4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Anoter option is to use pch symbol that works with `background` option, it can be used only when **pch = 21:25**.

```
plot(1, pch = 19, cex = 3, col = "red")
points(1, pch = 1, cex = 3, col = "black", lwd = 2)

legend("top",
       "sym",
       pch = 21,
       pt.bg="red",
       cex = 2,
       pt.cex = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice option :)

Comment: Thank you. This is also a great answer with tidier code.